# how to move multiple OS installed by berryboot to hdd?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have 5 OS that came pre-installed with berryboot on my 16GB SD card.
I have a 2TB external hdd. I plan to use it as my media server/player/NAS/torrentbox.
From research, I learnt that it's advisable to move OS from SD to external hdd, so as to improve the life of the SD card.

Can I create 2 partitions on the hdd (1st one, let's say, of 32GB), and use this 1st partition to have all my OS along with their root file systems?
Any link with instructions for how I move the OS from SD to HDD would be useful. 
(FYI, I have not yet made up my mind about using Raspbian+omxplayer vs OpenElec. Tried booting and playing around with both of them; Will check the performance and decide later)

Thanks, 
-ftp

Comment: *"From research, I learnt that it's advisable to move OS from SD to external hdd, so as to improve the life of the SD card."* I did some research and even testing: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96774/stress-testing-sd-cards-using-linux  and that is not true; leaving the OS on the card for normal operation will not wear the card out in a *reasonable* amount of time -- think *decades* of use.  If you stick an SD card in a high MP camera and shoot gigabytes of data all day every day, you will eventually wear it out.  But just running an OS -- never, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and found (I think) the best tutorial for moving the OS from sd to hdd at Raspberry Pi Forum:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=44177

My external usb hdd has different partitions and no problem to set them. I only use the sd card with the /boot config.